# How to do concurrent executions in python?

Tags: python, opencv, parallel-processing, face-recognition

##### Description

I have a file `FaceDetection.py` which detects the face from webcam footage using `opencv` and then writes frames into `output` object, converting it into a video. If the face is present in the frame then a function `sendImg()` is called which then calls the function `faceRec()` from another imported file. At last this method prints the face name if the face is known or prints "unknown".

##### Problem I am facing

face recognition process is quite expensive and that's why I thought that running from different file and with a thread will create a background process and `output.write()` function won't be interrupted while doing face recognition. But, as `sendImg()` function gets called, `output.write()` function gets interrupted, resulting in skipped frames in saved video.

##### Resolution I am seeking

I want to do the face recognition without interrupting the `output.write()` function. So, resulting video will be smooth and no frames would be skipped.

Here is the `FaceDetection.py`

```
import threading
from datetime import datetime
import cv2
from FaceRecognition import FaceRecognition

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('face_cascade.xml')
fr = FaceRecognition()
img = ""

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
path = 'C:/Users/-- Kanbhaa --/Documents/Recorded/'

vid_name = str("recording_"+datetime.now().strftime("%b-%d-%Y_%H:%M").replace(":","_")+".avi")
vid_cod = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MPEG')
output = cv2.VideoWriter( str(path+vid_name) , vid_cod, 20.0 ,(640,480))

def sendImage(imgI):
    fr.faceRec(imgI)

while True:
    t,img = cap.read()
    output.write(img)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray,2,4)

    for _ in faces:
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=sendImage,args=(img,))
        t1.start()

    cv2.imshow('img',img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0XFF == ord('x'):
        break
                                                        
cap.release()
output.release()
```

Here is the `FaceRecognition.py`

```
from simple_facerec import SimpleFacerec


class FaceRecognition:
    def __init__(self):
        global sfr
        # Encode faces from a folder
        sfr = SimpleFacerec()
        sfr.load_encoding_images("C:/Users/UserName/Documents/FaceRecognitionSystem/images/")

    def faceRec(self,frame):
        global sfr
        # Detect Faces
        face_locations, face_names = sfr.detect_known_faces(frame)
        for face_loc, name in zip(face_locations, face_names):
            if name != "Unknown":
                print("known Person detected :) => " + name)
            else:
                print("Unknown Person detected :( => Frame captured...")
```

Imported file `SimpleFacerec` in the above code is from youtube. So, I didn't code it. It can be found below.

[SimpleFacerec.py](https://drive.google.com/file/d/104CiwSee2zQfkXYkffkkk3c_kSDyfgAt/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

you write it wrong. It should be

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=sendImage, args=(img,))
```

Comment: Even after correcting the threading line, issue still persists. May be threading isn't the good choice for this kind of work.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing, but don't used underscore.

```
for index in faces:
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=sendImage,args=(index,))
    t1.start()
```

Comment: underscore is just a replacement of the temporary variable. It doesn't change anything. Although I tried it and even after replacing underscore it doesn't change the performance.

Comment: What if you change  this args=(faces,) or remove args?

Comment: This args is passing the frames to the function which is going to be processed. So, we can't remove that